# Caliburn Micro with Treeview Context Menu

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have my hierarchical treeview binding wonderfully to my ViewModel using Caliburn Micro.  (The ViewModel has an Items property that returns an ObservableCollection - the treeview is named to this Items property - nothing wrong with the binding).

However the issue comes up with the context menu.  The menu fires a method on an instance of the object that the treenode represents.  What I rather want to achieve, is to have the menu fire a method on my root ViewModel, passing to it as a parameter the instance of the object  represented by the clicked treenode.
Here is my XAML:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:TaskGrouping}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"
                           FontWeight="Bold">
                        <Label.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Add New SubFolder"
                                          cal:Message.Attach="AddNewSubfolder" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Remove this folder"
                                          cal:Message.Attach="RemoveFolder" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Label.ContextMenu>
                    </Label>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

What changes do I need to make to my XAML in order to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ContextMenus` are located in a separate visual tree from everything else - it can be a pain to get the bindings right (I often have 10-15 minutes of fighting the bindings on them to get them right!)

You've got your `Message.Attach` attached property set, all you need to do is ensure that the action target is pointing to the VM rather than the data item. You can use `Action.TargetWithoutContext` to specify the target for actions (CM will otherwise use `DataContext`)

You will also need to get a binding path which points to the other visual tree - try using `RelativeSource` bindings - the `ContextMenu` also has a property called `PlacementTarget` which should point to the element that the `ContextMenu` is attached to

So possibly:

```
cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Label}}"
```

or

```
cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext}"
```

You might have to experiment as I often get this *almost* right first time!

EDIT by OP(Shawn):
This is what worked for me eventually:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Name}"
                               Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
                            <Label.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu
                                    cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Run Task Now" cal:Message.Attach="SomeRootViewModelMethod($dataContext)" />
```